# The usage of possessive s

Tags: possessives

Normaly we would say James's car but is it also acceptable to say for instance the car of  James or it sounds just awkward and no one would say that?

Comment: It sounds awkward but that doesn't mean nobody would ever use it. People say awkward things a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine) gives some guides on the use of the 's and the of-phrase:

> When we **don’t use of**

> When we are talking about **things that belong to us**, relationships and characteristics of people, animals, countries, categories, groups or organisations made up of people, we usually use ’s:The **men’s** dressing room is on the left at the end of the corridor. Not: The dressing room of the men … The **cat’s** paw was badly cut. Not: The paw of the cat …

> When we **don’t use ’s**

> We don’t use ’s when the noun is not a person, animal, country, organisation, etc., or when the noun phrase is very long

OP's example belongs to the first category.

As an aside, there are different guides on whether to use 's or just the apostrophe for proper names ending with s.  The same dictionary says

> When a first or second name ends in -s, we can either add ’ or ’s. It is **more common** to use ’ than ’s.

> Is that **James’** car? (or Is that **James’s** car?)

We can use either one but should be consistent.